# Improving this view

Tags: website-design, interface

Currently, I'm working on creating a view from where the main purpose of it is to show details about a user.

Here is the initial view that is given when a user comes to the screen ("Certificates") is primarily what they will be looking at when using this view and the other pieces are supplemental but need to be available easily and quickly.

[image: Initial View]

Here is what it looks like when another header is expanded (so on and so forth)

[image: Header expanded]

I'm looking for advice on how I can improve this design.  I have to admit, looking at it on here, I think more space could be used between the header and the above expanded content.

I would like some comments about the icons next to the headers as well.  Is this a good design or should I include something in the expanded content instead?  Every button has a tooltip associated with it to define what the action does.

Comment: What do you think does not work in this layout?

Comment: The "icon" buttons seem a little clumsy to me, but I don't want to force the user to have to expand the content just to edit or add a new item.  Perhaps the spacing between the expanded content and the following headers.  Maybe fonts also...spacing in general...yea..a few things.  I'm mostly a developer trying hard to be better at UX so I can make my applications more desirable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Dark colored areas of sections' headers dominates visually. It distracts an eye. More lighter is more clear.
2. Text left paddings are too small. Increase it.
3. There is too little space between unfolded sections. Add space to separate them.

This view is more clear.
[image]

Comment: This is where I wondered about the icons for the actions on the header.  The `+` is an "Add New [Item Type]" action while the chevron initiates the roll up/down actions.

Comment: @Justin So pluses in the section headers are add actions? It's more clear to use Add button. Now it looks like Certificates+ instead of action. I've updated the answer, take a look at the picture.

Comment: Is it really more natural to add the roll up/down action on the left side vs the right?  I see the appeal of the right side holding the action

Comment: It's used widely in foldable tree view, so it should be clear triggers for interaction. Also it will be good to handle clicks on the headers for triggering fold/unfold interactions.

Comment: You mention lighting up the header, but I don't want it completely devoid of color.  How much light should it be made before if becomes a distraction again?  Started with `#3C73A8` and am looking at `#568DC2` now

Comment: Color is used to make distinction between elements. But you use font formatting already for this aim. You really need no double distinction, as it is perceived as clutter. The more contrast color, comparing to background, the more it attracts an eye. Several such elements create distraction, as eyes tend to jump between those elements. Sorry, cannot check those colors now.

Answer (score 3):

The interaction concept of these expand/contract content areas is not bad. There is some visual noise being added to the screen that is rather unnecessary though.

Couple of suggestions for you.

**Reducing Visual Clutter:**

• Attempt to eliminate the alternating row colors, or reducing the gray value of these (they are breaking up the view and making it seem "striped").

• Place additional padding below each section. Try 30-40 pixels to start to separate the content areas from one another.

• Consider changing the tint of your large blue headers for the *non-expanded* content areas. Drop the tint a few values to make these recede from the users vision when inactive.